# Duplicated simple types while generating of jaxb classes

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xml-namespaces

I have defined multiple xsd files in binding.xjb file, some of them have similar dependency (schema locations with urls but different version) and when I am attempting to generate classes I am getting errors that some simple types are already defined. How to resolve this conflicts? Thank you in advance for samples of code.

binding.xjb

`

```
<!-- Raise theEnumMemberSizeCap limit -->
<jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMaxMembers="1024"/>
</jxb:bindings>

<jxb:bindings
    schemaLocation="first_v1-0.xsd">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:package name="com.test.generated.first"/>
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
</jxb:bindings>

<jxb:bindings
    schemaLocation="second_v1-0.xsd">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:package name="com.test.generated.second"/>
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

`

schema first and second have schemalocations included to different version but includes the same type for instance:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.somenamespace.com/" schemaLocation="https://www.somenamespace.com/schema/additional-structure_v1.xsd"/>

<xsd:import namespace="http://www.somenamespace.com/" schemaLocation="https://www.somenamespace.com/schema/additional-structure_v2.xsd"/>
```

that includes common

```
<xsd:simpleType name="SomeSimpleType">
    ....
</xsd:simpleType>
```

that causes error, because SomeSimpleType is already defined in another version of dependency additional-structure

Comment: I have already added the code

Comment: there is a minor bug in your code. Fixing this minor bug in your code will be giving you the expected result.

Comment: @user1241241 could you indicate the place?